# ¿Cuál es el origen de "tumbaburros"?

Tags: etimología, significado, coloquialismos, méxico

El *tumbaburro* es un protector delantero de camiones ligeros, también conocida como la *burrera*:

[image: Burrera de troca]

Sin embargo el DRAE solamente acepta [*tumbaburros*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=atH85rq) (plural, fíjese) como una forma mexicana y festiva (!) de *diccionario*. Hay un ejemplar famoso del Jiménez (1977) que trata de la jerga mexicana:

[image: Tumbaburro de la Picardia Mexicana]

Lamentablemente la palabra no aparece en mis diccionarios de jerga, ni siquiera en el que está arriba. Buscando su significado, pregunté a un amigo chilango, que me sugirió que tumbar a un burro es darle satisfacción sexual, que despues se duerme. Luego noté que existe el dicho, "tumbado del burro", [reportado como "loco"](http://www.diccionariosdigitales.net/GLOSARIOS%20y%20VOCABULARIOS/JERGA%20MEXICANA-CALICHE.htm).

¿Cuál es el origen de los sentidos no literales de la palabra? ¿Se ha visto otro *tumbaburro* mas allá de la obra del Jiménez?

Comment: Busqué la palabra con google.  Parece que la acepción de *diccionario* no es sólo en México.  García Márquez cuenta que después de buscar la diferencia entre *camello* y *dromedario*, su abuelo "me puso el glorioso tumbaburros en el regazo y me dijo: —Este libro no sólo lo sabe todo, sino que es el único que nunca se equivoca."

Comment: El [Diccionario de americanismos](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=Ryi7DCn7Ox0Aew6szQI) recoge también _Ec, Pe. mataburros, accesorio de metal que se coloca en los vehículos._

Comment: Parece ([1](https://mx.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080507113439AA0S5om), [2](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/diccionario-mataburros-tumbaburros.10072/)) que le llaman _tumbaburros_ o _mataburros_ por el hecho de que hace menos burra (inculta) a la gente

Comment: Buena teoría, fedorqui, bien puede ser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La web WikiLatina dice de [mataburros](http://www.wikilatina.com/mataburros) que

> El origen del término se cree que fue en el área de la ventosa en Mexico, en donde era común que los burros cruzaran la carretera, y los camiones y vehículos se accidentaban al chocar con ellos, por eso se instalaba este dispositivo.

Por eso al "parachoques" se le conoce coloquialmente como *mataburros* o *tumbaburros*.

*Tumbaburros* parece tener sólo los significados de:

a) diccionario en especial uno de gran tamaño (como indica fedorqui en los comentarios, posiblemente porque el diccionario "hace menos inculta [burra] a la gente).

b) parachoques grande que se instala al frente de los vehículos (por lo explicado anteriormente).

*Mataburros* parece ser un equivalente de *tumbaburros*, pero el primero por lo visto también hace referencia (en Uruguay) a un

> Hueco en el suelo cubierto por barras paralelas en la entrada de una finca, que impide el paso del ganado paro permite en de las personas y vehículos.

(también se menciona esa acepción en [esta web](http://365palabras.blogspot.com/2012/05/mataburros.html))

Así que el origen del término parece estar en el habla coloquial, y viendo que puede haber varios significados, es razonable pensar que se han visto más *tumbaburros* que los de la obra de Jiménez y que es él quien hace referencia a algo que ya existe el el habla popular.

Comment: Confirmo el sentido educativo al encontrar "El pequeño tumba burros: Diccionario de dudas", pero del sentido de tamaño, no śe: aquellos libros no parecen muy grandes.